# How to overwrite the confirm_login_allowed function in the Django AuthenticationForm class?

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-authentication, django-login

I need to overwrite the confirm_login_allowed error message when user is inactive. I do not currently have any custom login views or forms. I do have a custom model backend and overwriting the authenticate function but that is in my middleware file.

I'd rather not add it to the middleware because I just need this at login only.

I'd appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you read the login source code:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/_modules/django/contrib/auth/views/

Solution:
You need to create a form that is a subclass of AuthenticationForm in django.contrib.auth.forms and add overwrite the confirm_login_allowed in there such as below:

in forms.py:

```
class CustomAuthenticationForm(AuthenticationForm):
    def confirm_login_allowed(self, user):
        if not user.is_active:
            raise forms.ValidationError(
                _("Your account has expired. \
                Please click the renew subscription link below"),
                code='inactive',
            )
```

Update your urls.py file - update the kwargs for the login view:

```
url(r'^login/$', login, {'authentication_form':forms.CustomAuthenticationForm}, name='user_login'),
```